# Using jRecorder in a Liferay 6.1 portlet

Tags: jquery-plugins, liferay-6

I am using [jRecorder](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/) for recording audio & send it to the server. I have tested it out on a simple web application with a servlet, everything is works fine.But  it is creating problem when I integrate the same code into a liferay portlet.It uses a host path, to specify the servelet for uploading, in Liferay I am using the Action URL in place of servlet url, but this url is not being hit from the underlying swf.Please provide me any solutions..

Answer (score 0):

You must try Resource URL in place of Action URL.

And please place some demo code with problem, so one can help you better.